# How can i highlight (color) specific row in php from color in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, css

#### Tables

So i have 2 tables: 
1st has id, username, lastname, title
2nd has id, title, color

and i can create entries in those tables.

### The problem

what i need to do is if i submit a form like this into 2nd table: Admin, blue; and a form like this in the first table: someuser, lastname, Admin i get the whole row in displayed table colored blue,
similarly if i enter Guest, red; and anotheruser, lastname, Guest i get the whole row red and so on..

so far i can only make the 2nd table to have different colored rows:

#### What i have so far

```
    <?php
    $q = "SELECT *";
    $q .= "FROM tbl1";
    $r = mysql_query($q,$connection);
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
    ?>
     <?php
        $q = "SELECT *";
        $q .= "FROM tb2";
        $r = mysql_query($q,$connection);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
        {
        ?>


  The second table is used only for color


<tr style="background-color: <?php echo $row['color'];?>">
  <td>some data from table 1</td>
</tr
  <?php }}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your closing tr tag.

```
<?php
    $q = "SELECT *";
    $q .= "FROM tbl";
    $r = mysql_query($q,$connection);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
    ?>
  <tr style="background-color: <?php echo $row['color'];?>">
  <td>somedata</td>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
```

Comment: change td to tr, because he is missing a TR not a TD.